# Why DCGAN with non-convolutional discriminator doesn't learn?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, dcgan

I tweaked the [DCGAN-Tensorflow code](https://github.com/carpedm20/DCGAN-tensorflow), changing its discriminator architecture to a [non-convolutional net](https://github.com/Instassa/DCGAN-tensorflow/blob/master/model.py#L378). This makes the discriminator and generator losses to go in parallel since the very beginning of learning, like that:
[image]
The numbers of both losses aren't constant, they do bounce around, but very slightly. The generated output is not good at all - the model doesn't seem to learn.

**Question:** Have anyone come across something like this before? What can be the issue?

---

The full git repository is available [here](https://github.com/Instassa/DCGAN-tensorflow/blob/master/model.py).

And this is the code for the edited discriminator, that broke the code:

```
  def discriminator(self, image, y=None, reuse=False):
    with tf.variable_scope("discriminator") as scope:
      if reuse:
        scope.reuse_variables()

      if not self.y_dim:
        im = tf.reshape(image, [64, 160])

        self.h0, self.h0_w, self.h0_b = linear(im, 1024, 'd_h0', with_w = True)
        h0 = tf.nn.tanh(self.g_bn0(self.h0))
        self.h1, self.h1_w, self.h1_b = linear(h0, 1024, 'd_h1', with_w = True)
        h1 = tf.nn.tanh(self.g_bn1(self.h1))
        self.h2, self.h2_w, self.h2_b = linear(h1, 160, 'd_h2', with_w = True)
        h2 = tf.nn.tanh(self.g_bn2(self.h2))
        self.h3, self.h3_w, self.h3_b = linear(h2, 2, 'd_h3', with_w = True)        
        h3 = tf.nn.tanh(self.g_bn3(self.h3))            
        h4 = linear(tf.reshape(h3, [self.batch_size, -1]), 1, 'd_h4')

        return tf.nn.sigmoid(h4), h4
```

Instead of the original one:

```
  def discriminator(self, image, y=None, reuse=False):
    with tf.variable_scope("discriminator") as scope:
      if reuse:
        scope.reuse_variables()

      if not self.y_dim:
        h0 = lrelu(conv2d(image, self.df_dim, name='d_h0_conv'))
        h1 = lrelu(self.d_bn1(conv2d(h0, self.df_dim*2, name='d_h1_conv')))
        h2 = lrelu(self.d_bn2(conv2d(h1, self.df_dim*4, name='d_h2_conv')))
        h3 = lrelu(self.d_bn3(conv2d(h2, self.df_dim*8, name='d_h3_conv')))
        h4 = linear(tf.reshape(h3, [self.batch_size, -1]), 1, 'd_h3_lin')

        return tf.nn.sigmoid(h4), h4
```

Comment: I have tested your git code, it is working as expected. In a GAN, it is normal to have this kind of parallel losses. The G and D are learning and becoming better, but they have both reached a competitive equilibrium.

Comment: So, if the data generated in a process of training are not looking like the anything, does it mean that the larger architecture is required for the discriminator?

Comment: Not necessarily. But in this case, both the original generator and the modified one are generating good samples.